# Python blocktrans with not working

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django website and I'm using a list like so in my views.py file:

```
EventsList = []

EventsList.append({'ipaddress':'192.168.200.1', 'starttime':'02/12/2013 13:59:42', 'endtime':'02/12/2013 14:59:42'});

EventsList.append({'ipaddress':'192.168.200.2', 'starttime':'02/12/2013 13:59:42', 'endtime':'02/12/2013 14:59:42'});

EventsList.append({'ipaddress':'192.168.200.3', 'starttime':'02/12/2013 13:59:42', 'endtime':'02/12/2013 14:59:42'});
```

On my HTML page I wish to do the following:

```
<p><b>{% blocktrans with len(EventsList) as Count %}{{ Count }}</b> events detected from <b>{{ first_session_start_time }}</b> to <b>{{ last_session_end_time }}</b>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

But I get the error on page load:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '(Events)' from 'len(Events)'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. In template you need [length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length) template tag:

```
<p><b>{% blocktrans with EventsList|length as Count %}{{ Count }}</b> events detected from <b>{{ first_session_start_time }}</b> to <b>{{ last_session_end_time }}</b>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

In templates you can not execute Python code. The template language has its own way of dealing with things.

Comment: Thanks,The EventsList|Length is reporting that it is length 0, when in fact there are several items in it.

Comment: Are you passing properly the `EventsList` in request context?

Comment: I'm passing it like so:EventsList = [] EventsList.append({'ipaddress':'192.168.200.1', 'starttime':'02/12/2013 13:59:42', 'endtime':'02/12/2013 14:59:42'})response_dict['EventsList'] = EventsList return render_to_response('mypage.html', response_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))